# Hibernate performance: EntityEntryContext.downgradeLocks()

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, entitymanager

I was profiling a slow spring boot + hibernate application and found that approximately 20%-30% (increasing with time) of the time is used by

```
org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext.downgradeLocks()   

org.hibernate.engine.internal.EntityEntryContext.downgradeLocks()   313 28,821
       org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.afterTransactionCompletion()    313 28,821
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(boolean, boolean) 313 28,821
         org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(boolean, boolean)    313 28,821
          org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterCompletionCallback(boolean) 313 28,821
            org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$200(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl, boolean)   313 28,821
              org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit()    313 28,821
                 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit() 313 28,821
                    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit() 313 28,821
                       org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus) 313 28,821  
                           org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus)   313 28,821
                            org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(TransactionStatus)    313 28,821                         
                             org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport$TransactionInfo) 313 28,821                               
                               org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class, TransactionAspectSupport$InvocationCallback) 313 28,821   
                                  org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation)   313 28,821
                                     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed() 313 28,821

...
```

What does this method do?

I thought that this method could take so much time due to a large entity manager but regulary calling clear() on the entity manager doesn't help at all. I tried to change the transaction size in both directions, but the performance was still bad.

The use case is validation of new data against existing data in the database.

Has someone an idea or some tips how to speed up performance and could explain to me what the method in question does?

Many thanks in advance!